# Python mixins and types, dependencies

Tags: python, oop, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I work on a project with a huge class. Initially they were implemented as functions that just get imported, like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47562412/5308802):

```py
def plot(self, x, y):
     print(self.field)

def clear(self):
     # body

@classmethod
def from_file(cls, path):
    # body
```

```py
class Fitter(object):
     def __init__(self, whatever):
         self.field = whatever

     # Imported methods
     from .some_file import plot, clear, from_file
     ...
```

But I think it's not the best solution, IDE is mad on the code because it cannot find `field` in the external methods and considers `classmethod` on some functions as an error. I hope mixins can help with it.

But I see the similar problem in this approach: mixin classes don't have a base class with all the common methods and fields specified ([an example in Django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/509d9da26fb92a8d566ec105ff40bb024803ceaa/django/db/models/functions/mixins.py#L18)), so IDE and linters cannot find definitions and understand the code correctly too... I tried to use some common base class, as the following:

```py
class FitterBase(object):
     def __init__(self, whatever):
         self.field = whatever

class FiterMixin(FitterBase):
    def plot(self, x, y):
         print(self.field)

    def clear(self):
         # body

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        # body

class Fitter(FitterBase, FiterMixin):
     pass
```

But the interpreter raises an error:

> TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution

Is there any solution to this problem? It's really important because the class contains dozens of big methods, and correct inheritance would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Python is trying to construct an MRO for `Fitter` in which `FitterBase` both precedes and follows `FitterMixin`; the former because `FitterBase` is listed first in the seance of base classes, the latter because it is the parent of `FitterMixin`.

To resolve that issue, simply swap the order of the two base classes:

```
class Fitter(FitterMixin, FitterBase):
   pass
```

There's no reason to list both, though, because `FitterMixin` already inherits from `FitterBase`:

```
class Fitter(FitterMixin):
    pass
```

As this makes more obvious, `FitterMixin` isn't really a mix-in class, because you aren't mixing it with anything. Or, don't make `FitterMixin` subclass `FitterBase`:

```
class FitterBase:
     def __init__(self, whatever):
         self.field = whatever


class FitterMixin:
    def plot(self, x, y):
         print(self.field)

    def clear(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def from_file(cls, path):
        pass


class Fitter(FitterBase, FitterMixin):
     pass
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the reply! As I said, our codebase is really big, there is a dozen of such mixin classes, and your case with `class Fitter(FitterMixin)` 1. is actually just inheritance, 2. it won't work the same well with 10+ mixin classes; there would be a need to design some inheritance tree which is not what I want.
And your last code sample is just what I described as a problem of mixins: IDE sees `self.field` in the `FitterMixin`, but it cannot confidently find a definition; the same with methods. My Q was about approach to solve this problem, is it possible?

Comment: Sounds like an IDE-specific problem, not a Python problem.

Comment: Oh, I found [a pretty similar Q](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55209849/5308802), probably this is what I'm looking for.